# XGBoost monotonic constraints don't work

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

XGBoost (0.6a2) ignores monotone_constraints. I use it in line with [tutorial](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monotonic.html), but

```
params_constrained['monotone_constraints'] = "(1,-1)"
```

causes the same results as unconstrained models.

Are monotonic constraints in production now? Does anyone have a successful experience?

Comment: Did u solve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: It works in R using library(xgboost)